# How to change vertical content's length depending on article's length?

Tags: jquery, content-length

If there's a vertical content slider which is 500px long, is there any way to modify this number with jquery, depending on how long is the (for example) "article" next to it?

Additional info: The content slider have numerous box in it, I used a wrapper with overflow:hidden, so I just need to know a way to measure the article's lenght then modify the wrapper's length (which is 500px by default).

Comment: you can't use height:auto?

Comment: Can you post the HTML please so it can be answered in context

Comment: $("#wrapper").height($("#article").height());

Answer (score 1):

```
$( function () {
if($("div").height() < $("article").height()) {
$("div").height($("article").height());
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps jQuery's [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function is what you're looking for.